# javaScript colourize each character in a string

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using javascript and jquery and I am trying to concantenate the date methods such as d.getMonth() into a string so I can later go through each character and change the color with jquery.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    var d = new Date();


        $("document").ready(function(){ //$ is jquerys way of selecting a dom element

            $("#one").append(d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDay() + "/" + d.getFullYear()
            + "/" + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());

            var myTextDate = $("#one").text();
            for (var i = 17; i < myTextDate.length; i++)
            {





            }
        });

            //$("span").css("background-color","black");
            function getRandomColor() 
            {
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
                return color;
            }

    </script>

    <h3 id = "one">Today's Date is: </h3>
```

This is my origional code. I tried appending them to the html document which works. Then I made a method that generates a random color. Now I want to change the color of each character. But changing each characgter to a different color is where I am failing.

Comment: **How** does it fail to work? Does it explode?

Comment: show more code - also, what is the result that you **are** getting

Comment: flip man, explosions aren't good. at least make the explosion look nice with CSS

Comment: You should do `(d.getMonth() + 1)`

Comment: I updated my question with more code as well as what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, so your question has nothing to do with dates, but with "colorizing" a text string. Well anyway, you should add 1 to the month as David said (`d.getMonth()` will return a number between 0 and 11), and probably concatenate a space between the date and the hour, instead of a `/`...

Comment: `$("document").ready()`  should be `$(document).ready` - no quotes around document.  `document` is a global variable, not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of each character, you will have to wrap each character in its own element. You could solve it using `<span>`s:

```
var string = "My String";
var result = "";
/* Let's run through each letter and wrap it in a span. */
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    var color = getRandomColor();
    result += '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + string[i] + '</span>';
}
/* Now write it to the document. It might be safer to add it to an existing ID as innerHTML
   because you might want to have control over this huge list of elements. */
document.write(result);
```

This is not very good performance wise when the strings get very long, though.

Heres a little improvement to your `getRandomColor()` function:

```
function getRandomColor() 
{
    /* You don't need to split, as strings are already arrays (of characters, that is) */
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: why write out string? It looks like you are rebuilding it in result

Comment: Yeah I noticed I made some mistakes -_- like going backwards, which is good for performance but bad for strings that are non-reversed :D

Comment: Thank you, any chance do you also no why if I put an alert("hello"); in it will not execute? I was working those earlier but for some reason it does not anymore.

Comment: It really depends where you put it. If you put it somewhere that never gets called, it never gets executed. Hard to say. I am also adding something you will find very useful for your current code, gimme a moment, I just saw it.

Comment: Ya it is not changing the color of the string.

Comment: Sorry thats because the combo of your function and mine results in doubled up `#`tags, just remove one (in my post I'll remove mine)

Comment: still nothing. result

Comment: still nothing. result += '<span style="color:"' + color + '">' + myTextDate[i] + '</span>';

Comment: Fixed it you string was incorrect. Please change this when you get the chance and thanks alot for the help :)                                            result += "<span style=\"color:" + mycolor + "\">" + myTextDate[i] + "</span>";

Comment: As an example this string was correct, you have to _of course_ change it to your string - but thats not the point of the example :) I'm going to leave it because people who might come across this later won;t see a solution in it if it only references your code directly. I believe this general example is better. Good luck with the rest of it!